# Are all actions on a transaction supposed to be included in the block?

Tags: transactions, action, blocks, inline-action, notification

I've noticed something strange that is confusing me. I have a transaction that includes multiple actions on it, but it appears that the "transfer" action did not get recorded in the actual block. You can see the transaction here with all its actions:

https://bloks.io/transaction/b4b8132ef87c8d443fd1afbf3700cca2c3e3c56df93248d6830ca641e4360f7d

However, if you lookup the block itself (#85243597):

```
curl -X POST https://api.eosnewyork.io/v1/chain/get_block -d '{"block_num_or_id":"85243597"}' > eosBlock.json
```

And then search for that transaction ID, only one of the actions is included, and the "transfer" action is missing.

What is going on here? How are these public block explorers getting the full transaction info if its not recorded in the block?

Answer (score 0):

The *sendexternal*-transaction is the only trx that is *send*, rest are inline-actions or actions instructed through notifications/dispatchers and are therefore not part of the block. Only explicit actions which are part of the transaction and the signature-calculations are part of the block.

See the hierarchical structure here: [bloks.io#85243597](https://bloks.io/transaction/b4b8132ef87c8d443fd1afbf3700cca2c3e3c56df93248d6830ca641e4360f7d?tab=traces)